# Using grunt-contrib-compress to zip multiple folders into multiple zip files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compress

I have this dir structure:

```
asdf
 |---a
 |   |---files
 |   |---folders
 |
 |---b
     |---files
     |---folders
```

I wanted to use `grunt-contrib-compress` (I suppose is the one I want), to end up with 2 zip files `a.zip` and `b.zip`

```
 a.zip
 |---files
 |---folders

 b.zip
 |---files
 |---folders
```

Is there any way to do this? I can't find anywhere something about having more than one output (it says nowhere whether it's possible or not). And the only other questions about `compress` are about making the zip without the root folder (which I would also like for this)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hello, did you achieve this and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like grunt-contrib-compress is not the best solution here. The task that addresses your problem is [grunt-zip-directories](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-zip-directories)

For your particular case the task configuration should be:

```
zip_directories: {
    asdf: {
        files: [{
            filter: 'isDirectory',
            expand: true,
            cwd: './asdf',
            dest: './zip',
            src: '*'
        }]
    }
}
```

What this task does is, it takes all sub-directories of './asdf' and zips them into separate zip archives and puts the archives to './zip' folder. So after execution you should have two files in './zip' directory: *a.zip* and *b.zip* as you asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The compress task does not provide that feature out of the box, but there is great workaround using a dynamic config:

```
grunt.dynamicCompress = function (path)
{
    var target = grunt.file.expand(path);

    for (var i in target)
    {
        grunt.config.set('compress.' + target[i],
        {
            src:
            [
                target[i] + '/**'
            ],
            options:
            {
                archive: 'your-dist-folder/' + target[i].toLowerCase() + '.zip'
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Run it with your target path:

```
grunt.dynamicCompress('your-target-folder/*');
```